# What is coffee garlic?

Tags: coffee, garlic

Gordon Ramsey did an AMA [on reddit. He said this](https://np.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/4qfwoo/hi_guys_its_gordon_ramsay_back_for_another_ama/d4so2ll):

> "I would go down the rouse of recently we've been using lots of dry
>   spaghetti, with lots of **coffee garlic**, chili, preserved lemons. Once
>   we've roasted off the garlic, the chili, the shallots folded in the
>   spaghetti, olive oil. We've been putting some really nice cans, tuna,
>   over the top of the spaghetti, so it's almost like a sort of quick
>   fish past the dish but your using cans, very good cans, of tuna. with
>   some fresh capers, parsley, and a little bit of preserved lemon.
>   Delicious!"

I'm not sure if this is a typo or not but does such a thing exist as coffee garlic?  What is coffee garlic?

Comment: Considering the massive number of typos and other errors, I'm pretty sure it's some sort of error. Either, as the AMA comments imply "confit" or "chopped"... or something else... but no amount of googling returns any hits for "coffee garlic".

Comment: I'm sure though you will find some recipes for _garlic coffee_...

Comment: I think this should read coffee, garlic. His grammar is awful, you notice he puts cans, tuna later?

Comment: By that logic, you'd have to add cans and tuna. Could lead to problematic texture and presentation. I'd assume he meant confit garlic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above and on reddit he probably meant chopped garlic. See, for example, [this video recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZKLBD_LHYw) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Tem62TM3Rg).

Comment: Not confit? It sounds much more similar to coffee than chopped does.

Comment: Perhaps, but chopped garlic is used much more often in Spaghetti recipes.

Comment: @Jefromi if it was the result of autocorrest, which it probably was, chopped is much closer to coffee than confit is

Comment: @Zackkenyon On the other hand, if it was the result of dictating, confit is much closer. Both are quite possible, so seems worth mentioning both, even if the conclusion is that "chopped" matches some of his recipes better.

Comment: @Jefromi I hadn't considered dictation as a possibility. That would make Mr. Ramsey a dictator though.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee garlic, is as suggested most probably a phone typo reply from Gordon Ramsay's AMA.

However, there is a youtuber who has a "spicy garlic coffee spaghetti" video (posted before the GR's AMA).  This consists of instant coffee, red (sweet bell) pepper, garlic and chorizo. 
Also if you care to research you'll find dishes with coffee and garlic together.